# Group data from 3 SQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to match some sql entries and group them like the fallowing:

workers_table

```
ID    |   worker
------+--------------
1     |    Smith
2     |    John
3     |    Luke
```

workers_tools_usage

```
worker_id    |   tool_id
-------------+----------
1            |    1
1            |    2
1            |    3
3            |    1
```

tools_table

```
tool_id    |   name
-------------+----------
1            |    hammer
2            |    wrenches
3            |    drill
4            |    screwdriver
```

And my desired match should look like this:

```
worker       |   tool
-------------+----------
Smith        |    hammer,wrenches,drill 
Luke         |    hammer
```

Is this possible using Mysql ? Tried some UNION but no luck.

Comment: Check again the tools_table. Are the column names correct?

Comment: Yes it's correct, that the table where I keep the tools that are used by workers, for example the user_id 1 used the tools 1, 2 and 3 so that's why: Smith        |    hammer,wrenches,drill (and on the tools table there are listed with the corresponding id.

Comment: Check again the tools_table not workers_tools_usage.

Comment: Yes, you're right, should be tool_id not worker_id, I did edited.

Comment: And the 2nd column maybe tool or name?

Comment: I edited as name.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: You did, but you also changed the name of the 2nd column of workers_tools_usage to tool_name, although the previous name tool_id was more suitable.

Comment: @forpas that is  fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the query as:

```
select w.id, w.worker, group_concat(t.tool)
from worker w  join
     workers_tools_usage wtu
     on wtu.worker_id = w.id join
     tools t
     on t.tool_id = wtu.tool_id
group by w.worker w.id;
```

I am answering for the following reasons

- No outer joins are necessary as the question is asked.
- To show an example of *meaningful* table aliases, which are abbreviations for the table names.
- To provide an answer with all the columns qualified by the tables they belong in.

Comment: One single question, found this during testing, if I have 2 entries in workers_table that share the same name because of the GROUP BY we will only get one entry after query, same for any duplicate entry in the workers table on the name value.

Comment: @bt19 . . . Your seems pretty clear on combining workers by name.  But based on your comment, I added the worker id to both the `group by` and `select`.  You don't actually have to select it, but otherwise you won't be able to tell the difference between the two rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try using group_concat() - I assume your tool table worker_id as tool_id

```
select worker,group_concat(tool)
from workers_tools_usage w1 left join worker w2 on w1.worker_id=w2.id
left join tools_table t on w1.tool_id=t.tool_id
group by worker
```

Comment: For any MS SQL/TSql users who stumble in here:
If your on SQL Server 2017+ you can use STRING_AGG() in place of GROUP_CONCAT()
If your on earlier versions it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select w2.worker,group_concat(t.tool separator ',') tool
from   workers_tools_usage w1 
left join worker w2 
on   w1.worker_id=w2.id
inner join tools_table t 
on w1.tool_id=t.tool_id
group by w2.worker
```